# Use private key with passphrase in phpseclib?

Tags: ssh, sftp, public-key-encryption, phpseclib

I've created a PHP script which enables SSH FTP transfer from server A to server B, using phpseclib. Everything works perfectly when I use this command of no matter which key length to generate the key pair that I use:

`ssh-keygen -b 2048 -t rsa -N ""`

The connection is done pretty much as specified [here](https://phpseclib.com/docs/auth/#public-key).

The problem is that, as soon as I use another key algorithm, for example `ecdsa` instead of `RSA`, I get a `phpseclib3\Exception\NoKeyLoadedException`, saying that the key could not be read. No matter for which key size.

And, same happens when I generate a key pair using the RSA algorithm (as in the example above), but when I use a passphrase (and include that passphrase as second argument in the `load()` function, as you can see [here](https://api.phpseclib.com/master/phpseclib3/Crypt/PublicKeyLoader.html#method_load)).

So, can I actually use private keys encrypted with a passphrase in phpseclib? [This](https://phpseclib.com/docs/publickeys/#openssh) may be useful, as the keys generated with a passphrase say "OPEN SSH KEY" in their comment header...

Comment: In the phpseclib docs you will find information about which key formats are supported, e.g. for [RSA](https://phpseclib.com/docs/rsa) or [EC](https://phpseclib.com/docs/ec). Your statement creates a key pair in OpenSSH format. It seems that _encrypted_ keys are generally not supported for OpenSSH, s. [here](https://phpseclib.com/docs/publickeys#common-key-formats).